# How do I get a wellness check done on my sister?

Tags: police, safety

I live in Las Vegas NV.  I need a wellness check done on my sister who lives in Red Bank, NJ.  She is elderly and her son is trying to control her and her money. Will the police go check on her?

Comment: Yes, but they will merely check that she is alive and well (i.e. has not fallen down the stairs). They will not (and cannot) try to determine mental competence or whether someone is trying to gain control of her assets. If she answers the door and says she is fine, they will take her at her word.

Answer (score 8):

Call the non-emergency line of the Red Hook Police Department and explain the situation and ask for a welfare check: 732-530-2700. [Police | Red Bank Borough, NJ](https://www.redbanknj.org/197/Police).

To report elder abuse, take a look at [Department of Human Services | Adult Protective Services (APS)](https://www.state.nj.us/humanservices/doas/services/aps/) and then contact the Monmouth County division:

```
Family and Children Services of Monmouth County
191 Bath Ave. 
Long Branch, NJ 07740
Phone: 732-531-9191
```